# Where can I find the current fee I can pay on my transaction live?

Tags: transaction-fees

I'm not sure what fee to put when sending btc. Is there a site where I can see what fee I can choose? It doesn't need to be priority send, but it just needs to get there within a day. Is there a site where I can see what fees will confirm or not?

Comment: If you Google for "current bitcoin transaction fee" you'll find many sites offering such estimates.  I feel like this has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this site: https://bitcoinfees.info

It tells you the recommended fees you'd have to use to get your transaction(s) confirmed within the next 1, 3 or 6 blocks. All the fees are getting updated once a day.

Keep in mind that you, as long as your wallet provides the option, can choose any arbitrary fee you want to, as miners have to decide for themselves wheter or not they want to include your transaction into their block.

Sending a transaction with a big fee increases your chance that a miner picks your transaction for their block as it would benefit him/her.